# Release Management Error

Tags: ms-release-management

We are trying to implement Microsoft's Release Management tool and started receiving the following error:

```
Failed to configure Microsoft Deployment Agent 2013 Service.  Error:  Cannot start service Microsoft Deployment Agent on computer '.'.
```

Having a hard time finding this error anywhere, RM is kind of new, and when we try to start the service manually it times out.  Hoping someone else has seen this, can use any suggestions

Comment: Have you successfully installed and configured the RM Server and Client? If so have you configured the Agent correctly as per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593701.aspx)?

Comment: We had.  We actually just figured out that it was somehow colliding with a Windows update.  Once we uninstalled the update, it worked fine.

Thanks for your comment!